# Can I add 'implements IName' to an already created object in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, interface, runtime, implements

I know that this sound odd, but third party infrastructure layer provide me an object that I want consume in app layer referring to it by a defined interface instead of the object directly.

Comment: Your object can not implement anything. It is an instance. Your class can do that - but **no**,you can not change that at runtime (_those who'll tell that he can - please, don't do this, tsss..._)

Comment: Thanks for you reply @AlmaDoMundo I edited the question, you are right, objects not implement anything, still I don't feel the phrase so consufusing... for example, the [instanceof](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php) operator can test if an object is an instance of a class that implement an interface without first get the class, what lead me to speak in that way, but you are right ;)

Comment: Your answer is no  - by design. Implementing an interface is the thing which is a structural definition, so it can't be changed on the fly.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. First I must to said that will not edit the question cos is hard put it in another way ;) at least for me, sorry;) Second, I don't want change structural definition at all, those objects (my bad! classes) already have the method that the interface defined but they just don't were declared that way explicitly. I just want found a way to a part of my code add that info, without change the class declaration, cos those classes are part of a third party code.

Comment: Changing declaration of thing, that class is implementing/not implementing an interface _is structural change_ even if class has all needed methods. It's obvious from meaning of what `interface` is

Comment: World is not so static, see C# decorators.

Comment: Your question is tagged with `php`. So I'm relying on that. You should define your classes/interfaces and links within them at startup, not at runtime. I can't imagine any use-case for redefining class definition such way at runtime

Comment: I just wrote that comment after read "that class is implementing/not implementing an interface is structural change even if class has all needed methods", just to show you such argument is not valid as explanation, and that exist scenarios in which one could need such levels of dynamism. To found usage scenarios just google "decorator pattern usage scenario" or something like that. Take a look [here](http://www.phpdesignpatterns.com/design-patterns/pattern-decorator/), is no the same, but deal with a very similar problem, my problem is simplest and seem to me overkill solve it that way.